# How to convert this while loop into a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{ 
int num, sum=0;
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

while (num>0)
{
    sum += num;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
}

printf ("Sum = %d ", sum);
return 0;
}
```

This is something I did.
I was trying to convert this while loop which add numbers until user entered 0 to a for loop. May I know what is my mistake here?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main ()

    {
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int sum=0;

    for (int i=num; i!=0; )
    {
        sum += num;
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only update `num` and `sum` in the loop. The `i`, which is used as the loop condition, is not updated. You should remove the variable `i`, which is not properly used, and fix the loop condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()

{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int sum=0;

    for (; num!=0; )
    {
        sum += num;
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, the structure of a for loop is `for(init_expression; loop_condition; expression_if_condition_is_true){code_block}` The `init_expression` is only executed once. The `loop_condition` is checked every time before executing the code block and the `expression_if_condition_is_true` is called if the condition is true, *after* the code-block is executed.

Comment: @jaaq `expression_if_condition_is_true` is executed *after* the code-block is executed.

Comment: I'd use `for (sum = 0; num!=0; )`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think a `for()` loop is necessary? It would be better to not repeat the call to `scanf()` and use a `while` loop instead. For example:

```c
int main(void) {
    int num, sum=0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) break;  // exit if there is no more input
        if (num == 0) break;                // also exit if 0 is entered
        sum += num;
    }
    printf("Total = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (1)` should be `for(;;)`. This will suit well as answer to "convert to for loop".

Comment: Well, OK. But a `for` loop with no initialization, test or update steps seems a bit redundant to me.

Comment: Some people regard `for(;;)` the idiomatic way for infinite loop. They say that you should understand this as `for(ever)` when you read code. It's not a normal `for`-loop - it's a separate idiom.

Answer (score 0):

One can use an infinite for-loop and insert a jump statement to terminate the loop. In this case:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{ 
int num, sum=0;
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

for(;;)  // pretty common and casual way of running an infinite for-loop
{
    if (num <= 0)  // executes if num is less than or equals 0
    {
        break;     // when break is executed this 'for' loop is terminated
    }

    sum += num;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
}

printf ("Sum = %d ", sum);
return 0;
}
```